# Kubectl Failed to pull docker image from private gcr.io repo

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am facing same issue on pulling docker image from private GCR it throws error

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE:TAG}:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: repository gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE:TAG} not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

Solution which I tried but still didnt fixed the issue:
1. delete the cluster and recreate
2. Provided Editor Storage Admin to the service account which is used to pull image.

Also when i try docker image pull using the service account auth, I am able to download the image to my local

```
docker image pull gcr.io/{PROJECT_ID}/{IMAGE:TAG}
```

Any suggestion \ help what am I missing

Thanks

Comment: If the registry is not public, you should log in with the command `docker login` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making sure that you have the proper scopes set up within your cluster for the service account to pull the image. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_users_and_other_projects_access_to_a_registry) is an article that provides step by step instructions on how to grant users permission to pull a image from a registry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the `kubectl` commands from your local machine?
If so, you should first configure `kubectl` context to GKE using,
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster --zone=europe-west2-a`

Read more information here
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials

You may have to install and configure Google Cloud SDK before executing the above command.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing

Comment: Yes I am running Kubectl from local machine and I had set the config context as mentioned but it still didnt work out. Also I tried doing this from google console shell.

Answer (score 0):

This issue raised mostly when we create the cluster with default service account (which doesn't have the permission to pull the image from GCR),so to resolve the issue, we can try the following:

We need to specify the scope as cloud-platform while creating the cluster so that the nodes in the cluster can acquire the permission to pull the image from GCR

```
gcloud container clusters create "test-cluster"   --zone "us-central1-a"   --machine-type "n1-standard-1"    --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write  --num-nodes "3"
```

**Or**

We can assign a service account while creating cluster which has permission to pull the image from Google Container registry:

```
*gcloud container clusters create "test-cluster" --zone "us-central1-a" --machine-type "n1-standard-1" --num-nodes "3" --service-account "XXXXXX@XXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"*
```

Regards